How to disable auto key repeat in Wayland?
For some ridiculous reason I need to disable key autorepeat.
I am told that "xset r off" or "xset -r" does the job. However, when I use the command nothing changes. Holding down a key, like "w" still results in repeated "w" being triggered.
$ wwwwwwwwwwwwww
$ xset r off
$ wwwwwwwwwwwwww
$ xset -r
$ wwwwwwwwwwwwww
$ xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  off    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00fbffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x49    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling):
  Server does not have the DPMS Extension

xset q tells me that autorepeat is indeed turned off, yet it still repeats.
Am I missing something? Can someone reproduce the behaviour? Is this a bug? And if yes, is there any alernative to xset?

Okay, after some further digging I understand what's happening. xset is a tool to configure XServer environment, yet Ubuntu 24.04 now comes with Wayland by default.
Starting Ubuntu with X11 instead by clicking the gear icon in login screen did the trick.
However, I actually like Wayland more. So is there any equivalent to xset -r for Wayland to disable Auto Key Repeat?
